# Is there way to ran this mysql query until the present date?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have mysql query I am supposed to run on a daily basis for each date/day until the present date. I want to run this query for each date until the present date. I am new to mysql so any advice would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
       SimNet,
        SUM(Amount) AS Amount,
        RechargeDate
    FROM
        Call.Recharge
WHERE
        DATE(Recharge.RechargeDate) >= '2023-10-01 00:00:00' AND 
        DATE(Recharge.RechargeDate) < CURDATE()
GROUP BY RechargeDate,Network;
```

I tried this

```
SELECT
       SimNet,
        SUM(Amount) AS Amount,
        RechargeDate
    FROM
        Call.Recharge
WHERE
        DATE(Recharge.RechargeDate) >= '2023-10-01 00:00:00' AND 
        DATE(Recharge.RechargeDate) < CURDATE()
GROUP BY RechargeDate,Network
```

and running for each day like this

```
SELECT
       SimNet,
        SUM(Amount) AS Amount,
        RechargeDate
    FROM
        Call.Recharge
WHERE
        DATE(Recharge.RechargeDate) = '2023-10-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY RechargeDate,Network
```

Comment: Please explain why your queries are not working. And why are you grouping by Network rather than SimNet?

Comment: Did you try to use `NOW()` instead `CURDATE()`? It returns current datetime

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT - except those who are arguments to aggregation functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY SimNet, RechargeDate`.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.